# Give example of actual Parenthesis Hell program

Tags: haskell, lisp, parentheses

Some of you may be familiar with [Parenthesis Hell](http://iwritethecode.blogspot.com/2009/12/parenthesis-hell-programming-language.html) (code [here](https://github.com/qpliu/esolang/tree/master/ph/doc)).  Well, nice way to waste some time between evening phone calls, right?

I successfully used ghc to compile these five files.  The interpreter seems to work if I run

```
$ ./ph
```

But since I don't really understand Lisp/cdr/car stuff very well, I quickly ran into trouble trying to do a functioning program.  I thought at least some of them were supposed to print something to standard output...

```
$ ./ph () ()
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
$ ./ph () (3)
$ ./ph () (())
$
$ ./ph (()())
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ ./ph "()()"  # suggestion in comment
ph: ()(): openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
$ ./ph  # actual behavior with returns
()
()
ph: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Needless to say, any attempt at using the Hello World in the "doc" led to lots of "syntax error near unexpected token" messages.  Any ideas?  Or does everything evaluate to `nil` and so this is just an elaborate [Lisp joke](http://clochure.org/), except with *two* actual compilers?  Thanks!

(Note: Lisp aficionados will be doing a service by teaching more people about how to interpret this parenthesis stuff, which I have to admit will be useful for me anyway in a completely different context.)

Edit 2: @dfeuer at least has a resolution which worked, though I do wonder whether it is possible to use interactively from the shell.

```
$ cat hello
(()()(()()(()()()()((()()(()(()((()((()()()((()((()()()((()((((()()(()()()()()()(((()(((()((()((((()(((()()(()()((()((()()()((()()(()()()()(()()()()(()()()()(()(())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
$ ./ph hello
Hello world!
```

Bizarre and yet awesome.

Comment: You are confusing `bash`, your command shell. Try something like `./ph "() ()"` maybe.

Comment: Or maybe there's a way to read in a file? No idea.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that too (the file).

Comment: Also, to those voting to close - please explain, I always try to do that on the rare occasion it is necessary to downvote something.

Comment: Bang!  It says it's an interpreter, so I'm thinking Python/IPython *shell*.  But you were right, just like of course you can do `python foo.py`.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it expects code in its arguments. It looks to me like it looks for filenames (and a command line option named `-v`).

It also seems like it only accepts one parenthesized expression per program. So something like `() (())` would be invalid but `(() (()))` would be okay (or at least well-formed). If you wanted to use this from the command line, you could use `echo` since it also reads from stdin:

```
echo "(()()(()()(()()()()((()()(()(()((()((()()()((()((()()()((()((((()()(()()()()()()(((()(((()((()((((()(((()()(()()((()((()()()((()()(()()()()(()()()()(()()()()(()(())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))" | ./Test
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a pull request for better documentation... `-v` seems to return the program itself, without a newline even. Thank you!